# Question tags at the end of the sentences

Tags: question-tags

I have 2 questions:

First, Which one is true between:

*I'm not your friend, am I?*

Or

*I'm not your friend, are I?*

I was confused since I knew we had to use *aren't I* instead of *amn't I* as question tags on positive sentences.

Secondly, and related to *aren't I* for positive senteces, generally people use *ain't I*. Is the term *ain't I* standard?

Comment: The pronoun "I" should be capitalized.

Comment: I am, you are, he is.  But there's a little quirk in the language in that "aren't" is used as the contraction for "am not" (though only in questions).

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/arent-i-or-are-i-not-correct-usage

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, i've edited it. So for the first question about "am I" and "are I" which one is true? "am I"?

Comment: "Am" is first person.  "Are" is second person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question comes after the comma and it is *Am I your friend?*

Certainly *Are* I your friend? would clearly not be correct.

The contracted phrase question gets stuck to the statement to ask if it is indeed not the case.

Use of *ain't* can be left to those who are trying to emphasize their rural, supposedly less literate, background